# Display Grid background pattern in sublimetext

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

I'm looking for a way to set a grid background style in sublime editor similar as gedit provides in preferences panel. The image below illustrates when the *Display grid pattern* is toggled on in gedit. It's possible to set this same feature in sublime?

[image: gedit display grid pattern]

Answer (score 1):

This is not currently possible in Sublime, no.

The background of files is always a solid color, whose color is controlled by the color scheme set in the `color_scheme` setting. That gives you the power to set a global color scheme background color, one that's specific to projects, and even ones that are specific to certain files or types of files, but it's always a solid color.

Comment: there's no way to use a PNG in the `.sublime-theme`?

Comment: @MattDMo I thought this might be possible by adding an image texture to  `sheet_container_control`, but that doesn't seem to do anything. According to the theme documentation: `"The sheet_container_control element is never visible to users in recent versions of Sublime Text 3."`. That's the only thing in the `sublime.log_control_tree()` output that seemed like it would be related to this area specifically. I must admit I didn't try to modify `pane_container_control`, though. It's not documented in the theme docs so I'm not sure what exactly it encompasses.